# Unable to serialize json keyvaluepair

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, deserialization, dotnet-httpclient

I have json, trying to deseralize the json using `Newtonsoft.Json` but i can't get some values in the list.

This is how my json look like

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "msg": "success",
    "code": 1,
    "data": {
        "country": "India",
        "countryid": "766",
        "operator": "Airtel India",
        "operatorid": "1371",
        "connection_status": "99",
        "destination_msisdn": "919895070723",
        "destination_currency": "INR",
        "product_list": "100,200,300,330,350,440,500,1000",
        "service_fee_list": "0.00,0.00",
        "retail_price_list": "7.50,14.50,21.50,70.50",
        "wholesale_price_list": "6.05,12.03,29.97,59.85",
        "local_info_value_list": "100.00,1000.00",
        "local_info_amount_list": "87.00,175.00,887.00",
        "local_info_currency": "INR",
        "authentication_key": "16809",
        "error_code": "0",
        "error_txt": "Transaction successful",
        "nick_name": "eldho",
        "price_map": {
            "100": "7.50",
            "200": "14.50",
            "300": "21.50",
            "330": "23.50",
            "350": "25.00",
            "440": "31.50",
            "500": "35.50",
            "1000": "70.50"
        },
        "local_info": {
            "100": "87.00",
            "200": "175.00",
            "300": "264.00",
            "330": "290.40",
            "350": "350.00",
            "440": "387.20",
            "500": "442.00",
            "1000": "887.00"
        },
        "service_map": {
            "100": "0.00",
            "200": "0.00",
            "300": "0.00",
            "330": "0.00",
            "350": "0.00",
            "440": "0.00",
            "500": "0.00",
            "1000": "0.00"
        },
        "operator_logo": "https:\/\/fm.transfer-to.com\/logo_operator\/logo-1371",
        "promo_code": 0,
        "benef_id": "16598"
    }
}
```

**Update : This local_info and service_map are dynamic data**

I usually create class of json model using [Json2charp](http://json2csharp.com/)

My seralization code is like this

```
using (var _client = new HttpClient())        
{        
    _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseServiceUri);

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("someparameter",token),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("id",myId.ToString()),        
    });

    var response = await _client.PostAsync(new Uri(baseAccessPoint, UriKind.Relative), content);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        throw new HttpRequestException(response.ReasonPhrase);
    }

    //I get value in this 
    var responseResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    //Unable to deseralize it.
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BeneficoryMobileDTO>(responseResult, new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        //NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        Error = JsonDeserializeErrorHandler,    
    });
}
```

My model look like this.

```
 [DataContract]
public class BeneficoryMobileDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public string status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string msg { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string code { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public BeneficoryMobileDetailsDTO BeneficoryMobileDetails { get; set; }
}

public class BeneficoryMobileDetailsDTO
{
    //I have removed some property to show things that doesn't work

    //THIS CAN'T BE SERALIZED
    [DataMember(Name = "PriceMap")]
    public dynamic price_map { get; set; }

    //THIS CAN'T BE SERALIZED
    [DataMember(Name = "ServiceMap")]
    public dynamic service_map { get; set; }

    //THIS CAN'T BE SERALIZED 
    [DataMember(Name = "LocalInfo")]
    public object LocalInfo { get; set; }


    [DataMember]
    public int benef_id { get; set; }
}
```

> Only `LocalInfo` , `ServiceMap` and `PriceMap` This properties are getting Null values. Everything apart it is serialized.

Pls let me know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Are the numbers always the same (i.e. 100, 200, 300, 330 etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause for your problem are the names of the properties. They can't be directly used in C# as identifiers [mustn't begin with a number (*identifier-start-character*)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx). So a property like this is invalid:

```
public string 100 { get; set; } // "100" is an invalid property name
// generates compiler error CS1519: Invalid token '100' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

json2csharp (which I didn't know before; really a nice tool!) gives you a hint as it generates the following class:

```
public class PriceMap
{
    public string __invalid_name__100 { get; set; } // invalid hint
    public string __invalid_name__200 { get; set; }
    // other props omitted
}
```

What you can do to let the deserialization succeed is annotate these properties (see the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm)) and tell json.net how they should be mapped:

```
public class PriceMap
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "100")]
    public string _100 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "200")]
    public string _200 { get; set; }
    // other props omitted
}
```

---

**Alternative:**

You don't have to use the classes like `PriceMap` etc. that were generated by json2csharp and can stick with `dynamic` as you already did in your question.

Basically the problem that occurs is just the name of the property. The result is always null, because you told json.net via the `DataMember`-attribute that it should map the json key `"PriceMap"` to the property named `price_map`. This won't work as there is no json key `"PriceMap"` in your json. Instead it's simply called `"price_map"`. So remove the `DataMember`-attribute and the property will be mapped correctly.

---

And as a side-note: there's a cool feature *paste JSON as classes* which autogenerates the necessary classes for you, if you don't wanna leave Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: This is dynamically generated so how could i map this

Comment: The nameing was issue. My mistake i didn't find this before.

Comment: Pls update your answer with the same , and i could mark it as answer